# HTML/CSS Table style

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm having trouble with my table. It isn't appearing how I'd like it to and I was wondering if anyone could help me fix any mistakes I might have made. Thank you so much!

Here is a picture of the table on the site

[image]

```css
table.foodTable{
 border:4px outset black;
 border-collapse:collapse;
 width: 100%;
 background-color:white;
 text-align:center;
 
}

table.foodTable caption{
 font-weight:bold;
}


table.foodTable thead{
 height:2.5em;
 font-size:1.1em;
}

table.foodTable thead tr th{
 padding: 0.5em 1.5em;
}

table.foodTable tbody tr td{
    border: 4px solid black;
    padding: 0.5em 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<table class = "foodTable">
 <caption>Food</caption>
 <thead>
 <tr>
  <th colspan = "2" style = "border-top:none;border-left:none;">&nbsp;</th>
  <th>Hate</th>
  <th>Dislike</th>
  <th>Indifferent</th>
  <th>Like</th>
  <th>Love</th>
 </tr>
 </thead>
 
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <th>Chocolate</th>
   <td> - </td>
   <td> - </td>
   <td> - </td>
   <td> - </td>
   <td>&#10004</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th>Ketchup</th>
   <td> &#10004</td>
   <td> - </td>
   <td> - </td>
   <td> - </td>
   <td> - </td>
   </tr>
   
  <tr>
   <th>Cheese</th>
   <td> - </td>
   <td> &#10004 </td>
   <td> - </td>
   <td> - </td>
   <td> - </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a `colspan ="2"` on the table thead `th` but not on the `th`'s within the tr's. Adding the colspan to the tr th's aligns the columns - however I am not sure its the best approach to have the `th` as the first `td` of the row. It would be better to apply styling to the td to give it the same style as the column heading but without the semantic definition of a `th` within the row.

```css
table.foodTable{
 border:4px outset black;
 border-collapse:collapse;
 width: 100%;
 background-color:white;
 text-align:center;
 
}

table.foodTable caption{
 font-weight:bold;
}


table.foodTable thead{
 height:2.5em;
 font-size:1.1em;
}

table.foodTable thead tr th{
 padding: 0.5em 1.5em;
}

table.foodTable tbody tr td{
    border: 4px solid black;
    padding: 0.5em 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<table class = "foodTable">
 <caption>Food</caption>
 <thead>
 <tr>
  <th colspan = "2" style = "border-top:none;border-left:none;">&nbsp;</th>
  <th>Hate</th>
  <th>Dislike</th>
  <th>Indifferent</th>
  <th>Like</th>
  <th>Love</th>
 </tr>
 </thead>
 
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <th colspan = "2">Chocolate</th>
   <td> - </td>
   <td> - </td>
   <td> - </td>
   <td> - </td>
   <td>&#10004</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th colspan = "2">Ketchup</th>
   <td> &#10004</td>
   <td> - </td>
   <td> - </td>
   <td> - </td>
   <td> - </td>
   </tr>
   
  <tr>
   <th colspan = "2">Cheese</th>
   <td> - </td>
   <td> &#10004 </td>
   <td> - </td>
   <td> - </td>
   <td> - </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```